# Android NDK - Add more Target API Level in Visual Studio

Tags: android, c++, visual-studio, xamarin.android, android-ndk

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and creating an Android App in C++.
I have one Android Packaging Project and a Android Library Project.

If I select the Android Packaging Project and go to:
Configuration Properties => General => Target API Level
The lowest I can select is KitKat 4.4, but I need to go down to 4.0.3.

But if I select an Android Library Project and go to:
Configuration Properties => General => Project Defaults => Target API Level
I can select down to Gingerbread 2.3.

So the question is, how can I select lower API level in a Android Packaging Project?

I have tried to install lowest API from Android SDK Manager and have tried to search on Google but not found anything helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Before you can select a Target or Minimum API level in Xamarin.Android, you must install the Android SDK platform version that corresponds to that API level. The range of available choices for Target Framework, Minimum Android version, and Target Android version is limited to the range of Android SDK versions that you have installed.
For more detail you can refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/android-api-levels?tabs=vswin)

Comment: How do I install a lower Android SDK in Visual Studio?